# Double quoted nested array won't work

Tags: php, syntax-error

Consider this :

```
$a = 'u';
$b[$a] = 'v';
$c[$b[$a]] = 'w';
```

This works fine:

```
php > echo $c[$b[$a]];
w
```

This also works:

```
php > echo '$c[$b[$a]]';
'$c[$b[$a]]'
```

However this leads to a syntax error:

```
php > echo "$c[$b[$a]]";
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']'

While a shorter version works:

```
php > echo "$b[$a]";
v
```

Why?

Comment: Just check: https://3v4l.org/rJbsY What is your php versions on the test machine and on the your server?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works both in CLI and on Apache2. Its more likely to do with code surrounding the assignment rather than the assignment itself.

Comment: @sectus : Just narrowed down the issue, this is not a server issue but a syntax issue. I'm still interested in the explanation, I'll rephrase the question entirely, please check again in 2 minutes.

Comment: Related, though it doesn't answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/812102

Comment: You can add braces in in-string array expressions, like `echo "{$b[$a]}";` - maybe that will help resolve the more complex variant?

Comment: @halfer : I tried several variations (e.g. https://3v4l.org/8aPGo), without success.  BTW I'm not trying to solve an issue (anymore), I'd just like to understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) there are two kinds of [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), simple and complex. Simple parsing will only work with a single dimensional array or object. So these will work:

```
echo "Valid: $foo[1]";
echo "Valid: $foo[bar]";
echo "Valid: $foo->bar";
```

But these will not:

```
echo "Invalid: $foo[1][2]";
echo "Invalid: $foo->bar->baz";
echo "Invalid: $foo->bar()[2]";
```

Complex parsing is what halfer suggested in his answer, which wraps the expression in curly braces, and will indeed solve your problem:

```
echo "Valid: ${foo[1][2]}";
echo "Valid: ${foo->bar->baz}";
echo "Valid: ${foo->bar()[2]}";
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: don't write PHP like this! If it is confusing to read then use an intermediate variable.

However, it can be fixed: it looks like PHP just wants the brace delimiters at the outermost edges of the variable:

```
<?php
$a = 'u';
$b[$a] = 'v';
$c[$b[$a]] = 'w';

echo "{$c[$b[$a]]}";
```

This is also fine as well:

```
echo "${c[$b[$a]]}";
```

In the first case, the whole thing is wrapped in braces, and in the second, the `$` is allowed outside of the brace construct to say that the next bit is a variable.